# What is the lowest dimension faithful representation of $A_n$ in characteristic 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, representation-theory

I know that $A_5$ is the group of rotational symmetries of an icosahedron, so in particular has a faithful 3-dimensional representation in characteristic 0. What about other alternating groups? I conjecture that  the lowest dimension faithful representation of $A_n$ in characteristic 0 is of dimension n-1 unless n is 3 or 5. $A_3$ has a faithful representation of dimension 1 over the complex numbers. Is this conjecture correct?

Comment: Certainly not in general. The minimal faithful representations for abelian groups are not always irreducible, unless the abelian group is cyclic. But maybe it is true for simple groups?

Comment: @mathlander For $A_4$, your conjecture does hold. The [group props wiki](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_alternating_group:A4) is a handy resource here.

Comment: My guess would be that it's either $n-1$ or $\frac{n-1}{2}$: the $n-1$ dimensional irreducible representation of $S_n$ either remains irreducible when restricted to $A_n$, or splits into two parts of equal dimension.  (That doesn't immediately exclude the possibility of some other representation of even dimension splitting where the $n-1$ dimensional one doesn't, but it seems unlikely for there to be a possibility of any other representation having that small a dimension.)

Comment: For $n \geq 6$, it is indeed the case that the smallest faithful representation (which for simple groups is the smallest non-trivial representation) is $(n-1)$-dimensional. This is stated on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group#Alternating_groups), but I'm sure a more authoritative reference can be found

Comment: Thanks so much!